# Sum two amounts per ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two amounts per ID:

```
ID      Amount
5864    556
5864    742
19504   1155
19504   1979
```

How do I create a query to return the total of the two amounts for each ID?

Like this:

```
ID      Amount
5864    1298
19504   3134
```

Comment: sum, group by... search on google aggregation functions.

Comment: What if there are more than two amounts? What do you want to happen then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Group By` function like :

```
SELECT ID, SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT_PER_ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: We here should expect some effort from the questioner. Just asking without showing no effort shows lazyness.